# repeat texture between a png

Tags: android, textures, nine-patch, tiling

I want to repeat specific rectangular area at centre of png drawable instead of repeating the whole image using 
`android:tileMode="repeat"` . If I 9 patch it will get stretched .any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Either, offline create a new PNG that only consists of the area you want, or dynamically, create a new Bitmap from the area you want and use this image for a drawable.